# where are aliases' namespaces defined?

Tags: laravel

let's say I have a controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use DB;

class LanguageController extends Controller
{
}
```

Imagine DB is registered as alias and is pointing to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class.`

I have questions now.

1) why does `use DB;` work in this controller ?  I think what it should be doing after `use DB` is that it should be trying to find the class inside the same directory that this controller resides.

2) I know that if I write `\DB::query` in a controller's function without even using "use" statement, it will work. I know that backslash means it tries to find the DB class in the global namespace. but where is the global namespace at all?

Comment: in `config/app.php`

Answer (score 0):

In `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => [

    'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
     ...........
    'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
    'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
    'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
     ...........
],
```

And all aliases and facads registered in `Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader` class

Comment: Also see `Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader` class

Answer (score 0):

1) `use DB` has nothing to do with the class being a controller, it's just how Laravel provides access to classes in other namespaces. It literally says "when `DB` is referenced from this file (which is in the namespace) instead refer to `DB` in the global namespace".

2) Prefixing a class with `\` lets you use an absolute class name by referring again from the global namespace. You can use it instead of `use DB` at the top if you prefer, but the latter is generally preferred. The global namespace just exists - anything that is not explicitly placed in a namespace will be in this global namespace.